# Windows 10, "hosts" file change automatic

Tags: windows, windows-10, artifactory, hosts, artifact

My "**hosts**" file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) change itself automaticaly allways.
The file include my project artifactory ip adress and its allways getting block with comment or the whole page delete and became blank.

[image]

It's happend randomly (between 4~10 times in a day of work)

I realy want to fix it and stop the auto changing.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Process Monitor tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to determine which process is changing the file.